# How to get specific value from json api with python

Tags: python, json, api, bots

So i have code that gets data from one api but i can only use frist 3 keys like message idk why is that  code:

```
   import requests
    import json
 
    result=requests.get('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2&page=1&offset=1&sort=asc&apikey=mytoken')
    result.status_code
    result.text
    result.json()
    
    print (result.json()['message]) # work
    print (result.json()['gas]) # or any other key dont work
```

Output from api:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":[{"blockNumber":"4620855","timeStamp":"1511634257","hash":"0x5c9b0f9c6c32d2690771169ec62dd648fef7bce3d45fe8a6505d99fdcbade27a","nonce":"5417","blockHash":"0xee385ac028bb7d8863d70afa02d63181894e0b2d51b99c0c525ef24538c44c24","from":"0x731c6f8c754fa404cfcc2ed8035ef79262f65702","contractAddress":"0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2","to":"0x642ae78fafbb8032da552d619ad43f1d81e4dd7c","value":"1000000000000000000000000","tokenName":"Maker","tokenSymbol":"MKR","tokenDecimal":"18","transactionIndex":"55","gas":"3000000","gasPrice":"1000000000","gasUsed":"1594668","cumulativeGasUsed":"4047394","input":"deprecated","confirmations":"7045304"}]}
```

i can only get status message ect.
when i try gas this is error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 11, in 
print (result.json()[gas])
NameError: name 'gas' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a few print statements to understand your response and debug

```
your_reponse = {
    'message': 'OK',
    'result': [{'blockHash': '0xee385ac028bb7d8863d70afa02d63181894e0b2d51b99c0c525ef24538c44c24',
    'blockNumber': '4620855',
    'confirmations': '7045304',
    'contractAddress': '0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2',
    'cumulativeGasUsed': '4047394',
    'from': '0x731c6f8c754fa404cfcc2ed8035ef79262f65702',
    'gas': '3000000',
    'gasPrice': '1000000000',
    'gasUsed': '1594668',
    'hash': '0x5c9b0f9c6c32d2690771169ec62dd648fef7bce3d45fe8a6505d99fdcbade27a',
    'input': 'deprecated',
    'nonce': '5417',
    'timeStamp': '1511634257',
    'to': '0x642ae78fafbb8032da552d619ad43f1d81e4dd7c',
    'tokenDecimal': '18',
    'tokenName': 'Maker',
    'tokenSymbol': 'MKR',
    'transactionIndex': '55',
    'value': '1000000000000000000000000'}],
    'status': '1'}
```

```
>>> your_reponse['result']
[{'blockHash': '0xee385ac028bb7d8863d70afa02d63181894e0b2d51b99c0c525ef24538c44c24',
  'blockNumber': '4620855',
  'confirmations': '7045304',
  'contractAddress': '0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2',
  'cumulativeGasUsed': '4047394',
  'from': '0x731c6f8c754fa404cfcc2ed8035ef79262f65702',
  'gas': '3000000',
  'gasPrice': '1000000000',
  'gasUsed': '1594668',
  'hash': '0x5c9b0f9c6c32d2690771169ec62dd648fef7bce3d45fe8a6505d99fdcbade27a',
  'input': 'deprecated',
  'nonce': '5417',
  'timeStamp': '1511634257',
  'to': '0x642ae78fafbb8032da552d619ad43f1d81e4dd7c',
  'tokenDecimal': '18',
  'tokenName': 'Maker',
  'tokenSymbol': 'MKR',
  'transactionIndex': '55',
  'value': '1000000000000000000000000'}]
```

```
>>> print(your_reponse['result'][0]['gas'])
```

```
3000000
```

Use this recursive function to work around changes in API response:

```
def price_of_gas(inp):
    def recursive_function(inp):
        if type(inp) is list:
            for i in inp:
                ans = recursive_function(i)
                if ans!=None: return ans
        elif type(inp) is dict:
            if 'gas' in inp: return inp['gas']
            for i in inp:
                ans = recursive_function(inp[i])
                if ans!=None: return ans
        else: return None
    ans = recursive_function(inp)
    return ans if ans else "Could NOT find the gas"
price_of_gas(your_reponse)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot man i have one more quesions is there any chance bot to check for api changes so if api change bot will print gas so i can monitor gas on ether network thanks :)

Comment: yes, create a recursive function that finds the key `gas`

Comment: Im braking my head id get it to work but how to run it every 30 sec and send it to discord im working on it for 5 hours i cant figure it out can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

See the JSON response carefully. Its a dictionary with three keys (status, message and result). The key result is a list having another dictionary inside.
JSON response:

```
{
   "status":"1",
   "message":"OK",
   "result":[
      {
         "blockNumber":"4620855",
         "timeStamp":"1511634257",
         "hash":"0x5c9b0f9c6c32d2690771169ec62dd648fef7bce3d45fe8a6505d99fdcbade27a",
         "nonce":"5417",
         "blockHash":"0xee385ac028bb7d8863d70afa02d63181894e0b2d51b99c0c525ef24538c44c24",
         "from":"0x731c6f8c754fa404cfcc2ed8035ef79262f65702",
         "contractAddress":"0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2",
         "to":"0x642ae78fafbb8032da552d619ad43f1d81e4dd7c",
         "value":"1000000000000000000000000",
         "tokenName":"Maker",
         "tokenSymbol":"MKR",
         "tokenDecimal":"18",
         "transactionIndex":"55",
         "gas":"3000000",
         "gasPrice":"1000000000",
         "gasUsed":"1594668",
         "cumulativeGasUsed":"4047394",
         "input":"deprecated",
         "confirmations":"7045304"
      }
   ]
}
```

So if you need to access the keys present inside the result dictionary, you have to nest your code accordingly.

```py
result.json['result'][0]['gas']
```